# Java loops that use imported files

Tags: java, loops

My code below works when a file imported contains 100 and more numbers. How do I get the loops to stop if there is less than 100 numbers left in the file? When there is less than 100 numbers, an error comes up as the array is not full.

```
try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int[] aNums = new int[100];
    System.out.print("Array contents: ");
    int i =0;
    while (i < aNums.length){
        generated = in.nextInt() ;
        aNums[i] = generated;
        System.out.print( aNums[i] );
        System.out.print(" ");
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Array contents: ");
    for (i = aNums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print( aNums[i] );
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
// Catch block, needed when using file input
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you want it to stop when there are less than 100 to read or when you have read at most 100 integers?

Comment: Both of those conditions plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the scanner if the file has more values:

```
while (i < len && in.hasNextInt())
```

Comment: i tried this but in.hasNextInt dosn't seem to work. Thanks for the reply

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt seem to work?

Comment: An error occurs as unrecognised condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
int[] aNums = new int[file.length()];
```

I didn't try it.. hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(in.hasNextInt()) {
  integerList.add(in.nextInt());
}
int totalNum = integerList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < 100 && totalNum - i > 100; i++) {
   aNums[i] = integerList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Can't use an arraylist

Comment: Nt sure just told to use arrays

Comment: then, firstly, scan whole file to get the length of integers, after that, use the `for` loop